# Регулярное выражение для логина в PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Почему не работает

```
   if(!empty($_POST['login'])) {
     if(preg_match('/^[А-Яа-я]+$/', $_POST['login'])) {
  echo '</br>' .'логин нормальный';
   }
   else {
  echo '</br>' .'логин плохой';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кодировка - utf-8 то нужно делать так:

```
if(preg_match('/^[А-Яа-я]+$/u', $_POST['login'])) {
```

обратите внимание на модификатор /u А также нужно что бы файл, где написана эта регулярка, тоже был в кодировке utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Про [set_locale](http://ru.php.net/set_locale) не забыл ?